# Craft Nitro PHP extension ext-zip * is missing

Tags: php, nitro

I'm not particularly tech minded so MAMP has served me well for a good while.  However I more recently decided to give Craft Nitro a try.  I got everything (Multipass and Nitro) set up really easy.  I then went to create a project and got the error PHP extension ext-zip * is missing.  I've seen this before and worked around it guided by [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac/58300437#58300437).

All good...  craft installed.   However, now i'm confused?  Why did I need to install an older version of PHP on my host machine (OSX) when Nitro is supposedly a self contained 'box' with everything needed for a Craft install?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you did `composer install` from your host machine instead of from inside the Nitro box?

Comment: Hi James! Inside the Nitro box?  The docs and a Mijingo vid tutorial both suggest the craft project should pre-exist?  So how do I do composer create-project from within Nitro?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run that `composer create-project` command from inside of your Nitro VM. If you run it on your host machine, it'll use whatever version of PHP your host machine has installed.

Do this:

1. Make sure Composer is installed in the VM by running `nitro install composer` from the host machine. https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/commands.html#install-composer
2. SSH into the box by running `nitro ssh`. https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/commands.html#ssh
3. Run `composer create-project craftcms/craft` to get a fresh new Craft project inside the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Brad.  This has worked for me.  Maybe the process of creating a project 'within' the Nitro box should be clearer in the docs?

Comment: @Martin Nitro 1.1.0 added a `create` command for setting up new Craft projects without relying on local PHP or Composer: https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/commands.html#create